# selected value get from db into Data list option using php mysql

Tags: php, sql, datalist, select-options

I need to get selected value from db into datalist box.Tell me how to do it. Here is the code.

```
<input list="Rank_Name" class="form-control" required>
                            <datalist id="Rank_Name">
                         <?php
                            $sel_cus = "select Rank_Name from ranks where Rank_Status=1";
                            $res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['Rank_Name'];?>"></option>
                           <?php
                            } 
                            ?>
                            </datalist>
```

Comment: <option <?php if($row['Rank_Name']){echo "selected";}?> value="<?php echo $row['Rank_Name'];?>"></option>

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but it only shows values from database , not showing selected values .

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $row['Rank_Name'];?>"><?php echo $row['Rank_Name'];?></option>  . Try this

Comment: i have a form where i shows list of users 

i want to edit user record by following code:

<a href="Update-users.php?id=<?php echo $row["User_No"]; ?>"><label type="text"  data-toggle="modal" style=" color: blue; font-weight: 600; " data-target="#">Edit </label></a>

when i click Edit button it take me to Update-users.php, where i show datalist box for rank 

i want to display previous entered rank name get auto selected from drop down

how to auto select rank name from list

Comment: can you update your question with code and the expected output.

Comment: i have a Update-users.php page where i display list of all users from database
i want to edit particular user , for this is use <a href="Update-users.php?id=<?php echo $row["User_No"]; ?>">
href="Update-users.php?id=<?php echo $row["User_No"]; ?>" this will lead to me to update selected user, in Update-users.php i show text fields where i am showing data of particular user like this: User Cnic  <input type="text" id="User_Cnic"  value=<?php echo $row['User_Cnic']?>> now i want to display ranks in datalist i successfully displayed ranks name in datalist problem

Comment: is i want auto selected rank in datalist while other rank names also shows in drop down

Answer (score 1):

If i understood right , you need to select value in dropdownlist with other value also. You can achieve this by doing this

```
    <?php
    $select1="select Rank_Name from ranks where Rank_Status=1"; 
    $q=mysqli_query($select1) or die($select1);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($q); //here you are getting name of person whose rank is 1
    ?>

    <datalist id="Rank_Name">
     <?php 
            $s="select * from ranks ";
            $q=mysqli_query($s) or die($s);
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
            { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $r['Rank_Name']; ?>"<?php if($row['Rank_Name']==$r['Rank_Name']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>
<?php echo $r['Rank_Name']; ?>
      </option>
            <?php } ?>
            </datalist>
```

In above code, this line `<?php if($row['Rank_Name']==$r['Rank_Name']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>` check if value are same from first query ,and if same then that option will be get `selected` automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
<input list="Rank_Name" class="form-control" required>
                            <datalist id="Rank_Name">
                         <?php
                            $sel_cus = "select Rank_Name from ranks where Rank_Status=1";
                            $res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {

                           echo "<option value=".$row['Rank_Name']."></option>";

                            } 
                            ?>
                            </datalist>
```

**try this code.**
im using echo `<option>` with while loop